# How to change opacity in disabled state of image in css

Tags: html, css

I would like to change opacity of image only when it is in disabled state like i'm doing for input `button` below:

```css
input[type="button"]:disabled {
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  border-radius: 4px;
  opacity:0.5;
}

img:disabled {
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
Normal button: <input type="button" value="Close" /><br>
Disabled button: <input type="button" value="Cancel" disabled="true"/>
<br><br>
Normal: <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkfB4.png" /><br>
Disabled: <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkfB4.png" style="opacity:0.5" disbled />
```

But it's not working for images, if I add `:disabled` in css. Please help me to get this.

Comment: I didn't see any image here.

Comment: Can you post your full html code with the image? That would be a good help!

Comment: What do you mean by "image in disabled state"? Disabled is usually used on form elements.

Comment: I agree with Bruno. The disabled attribute is really just for form elements. Why not just use `img.disabled` and `<img class='diabled' src=''/>`?

Comment: hi bruno, i'm performing onClick event on the image. So, in some cases i'm not allowing user to perform that event in that case i'm just disabling the image. To show the difference to user that it is disabled i like to change it's opacity like button above shown.

Comment: In that case, you could create buttons with image backgrounds, with buttons text and borders removed.

Comment: @BrunoKos, to do so i have to change everything right?

Comment: hi @ketan, please find the changes

Comment: Thank you @ivar, it's working fine in IE10, but i observed that even disabled not working on images in other browsers

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[As stated by W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html):

> An element is said to be actually disabled if it falls into one of the
>   following categories:
>
> - button elements that are disabled
> - input elements that are disabled
> - select elements that are disabled
> - textarea elements that are disabled
> - optgroup elements that have a disabled attribute
> - option elements that are disabled
> - fieldset elements that have a disabled attribute
>
> **Note:** This definition is used to determine what elements can be focused and which elements match the :disabled pseudo-class.

So, you should not use `:disabled` for images. You should to find some other way.

The best possibility should be to use an `input` tag with the type attribute `image`.

This way to can make use of the `disabled` attribute:

```css
input[type=image]:disabled
{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<input type="image" 
    src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkfB4.png"
    border="0" disabled />
```

If you don't want the a form to submit when you click it, you should add `onclick="return false;"` to the `input` tag.

---

Another possibility [as mentioned by @DevonBernard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742581/how-to-change-opacity-in-disabled-state-of-image-in-css#comment59158908_35742581) is to add a class disabled, and use CSS to get the opacity right.

```css
img.disabled
{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkfB4.png" 
    alt="Image" class="disabled">
```

---

If you do want to use the `disabled` attribute (even though you shouldn't) , another possibility is to use the attribute selector by using:

```css
img[disabled]
{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkfB4.png"
    alt="Image" disabled>
```

This is not the correct way, since the `disabled` attribute should not be used on images in the first place. Also some browsers might not support this (now or in the future).

Comment: using image as <input type="image"> disabled working in other browsers also

Comment: i think you are wrong, i mean before return false; only i have to add the rest of onclick events

Comment: Yes, you are right. The `return` stops the rest of the Javascript. The `return false;` should be at the end.

Comment: So, we can use image as input element. Then why can't we consider it as form element?

Comment: Because in this case it is not seen as a normal image, but as a submit button that is represented by an image.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 :disabled selector is usually used on form elements (checkboxes, buttons, etc), so if you want to apply opacity on img, you should use:

```
img.disabled
{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

So it is about the CSS class. I don't think I have an idea what could "disable state" on image mean actually, perhaps only an image state after you clicked it, but even in that case you can't go with "disabled" selector.

Comment: But i have many images like that, is there any other way to do this instead of adding class to every image?

Comment: There isn't, because as others also mentioned, disabled state doesn't work with anything but form elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the CSS selector for "disabled" state, which works fine in my case:

```
button[disabled] > img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Best
Manuel